# Angular - Como desabilitar um campo sem desabilitar o valor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Boa noite pessoal, eu tenho uma dúvida de angular bem simples. Eu tenho um formulário, tem um campo especifico que eu seto o valor por um patch value mas ao mesmo tempo preciso dar disable nesse campo. Porém após o disable, o dado não é enviado para o back end para ser inserido mais. Já fiz o teste e vi que só com o patch value, o dado é enviado normalmente e inserido no banco normalmente, porém quando faço um disable ele perde o valor e não é enviado para o back, eu já tentei o onlyself mas não obtive exito, gostaria da ajuda de vocês se possível, obrigado pela atenção. Ah eu sei que pelo html dá certo, mas gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de eu fazer isso no typescript desabilitando o proprio campo no formulário.

```
`iniciarSituacaoCadastro(){
        if(this.visualizar){
            this.formPesquisar.controls['situacaoMotivo'].patchValue(SituacaoMotivo.ATIVO);
            this.formPesquisar.controls['situacaoMotivo'].disable({onlySelf: true});
        
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar ao invés de desabiligar o campo, só setar como `readonly`, ou parar de trabalhar com formulário nesse caso e trabalhar os valores com ngModel, nesse caso não tem problema em desabilitar o campo pois o valor já está setado na variável por binding.

Comment: Valeu eu consegui por getRawValue().

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o que o Jason disse acima, é só usar a propriedade `readonly`.

O `[value]` vai ficar responsável por mostrar o valor no input.

Aqui um exemplo:

```
<input matInput type="text" name="situacaoMotivo" readonly="true" [value]="SituacaoMotivo.ATIVO">
```

Comment: Valeu eu consegui por getRawValue().

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você esteja usando a propriedade value do FormGroup.
Para pegar todos os campos, incluindo de inputs desabilitados, use o método getRawValue();

Exemplo:

```
const formValue1 = this.formPesquisar.value; // campos desabilitados não serão incluidos.
const formValue2 = this.formPesquisar.getRawValue(); // todos os valores serão enviados
```